# Is there an easy way to get the frequencies column wise?

Tags: r, frequency, likert

I have a list of Likert values, the values range from 1 to 5. Each possible response may occur once, more than once or not at all per column. I have several columns and rows, each row corresponds to a participant, each column to a question. There is no NA data.

Example:

| c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |

The goal is to count the frequencies of the answer options column wise, to consequently compare them.

So the resulting table should look like this:

| - | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

I know how to do this for one column, and I can look at the frequencies with `apply(ds, 1, table)`, but I do not manage to put this into a table to work further with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it, using `plyr`:

```
count_df = setNames(data.frame(t(plyr::ldply(apply(df, 2, table), rbind)[2:6])), colnames(df))

count_df[is.na(count_df)] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `table` in `sapply` -

```
sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, 1:5)))

#  c1 c2 c3
#1  3  1  3
#2  2  1  0
#3  2  2  1
#4  0  1  1
#5  0  2  2
```

This approach can also be used in `dplyr` if you prefer that.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% summarise(across(.fns = ~table(factor(., 1:5))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use a vectorized option in `base R`

```
table(data.frame(v1 = unlist(df1), v2 = names(df1)[col(df1)]))
   v2
v1  c1 c2 c3
  1  3  1  3
  2  2  1  0
  3  2  2  1
  4  0  1  1
  5  0  2  2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(c1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), c2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L), c3 = c(5L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```